# Pivot Rows into column and combine with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have TableX as

[image]

And TableY as :-

[image]

I want the desired new table creation as :-

**EntityId, EntityIdentification, DisplayName, AK, AL, AR, AZ, CA, CO, CT....**

MenuName col data from TableX should become pivot cols in the new table. DisplayOrder col is different for both tables and cannot be used to have a join.

Please suggest the pivot sql for this desired output.

Comment: what is your desired data output? and how your tables supposed to join each other?

Comment: The desired data output for new pivot cols such as AK,AL,AR,AZ etc. should be having a blank value for every row. It's like extending from TableY with extra cols from TableX.MenuName rows.. There is no join criteria between the tables..

Comment: then (and I think it's the only way here) you should write dynamic sql and execute your dynamically built query

Comment: If there is no join criteria then how can you match records from one table to the other?

Comment: Yes, i had to build the cols dynamically since there is no relation between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link -

[https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:766825833740](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:766825833740)

Answer (score 0):

```
select EntityId, EntityIdentification, DisplayName, AK, AL, AR, AZ, CA, CO, CT from 
    (select  EntityId, EntityIdentification, DisplayName, GlobalMenuID,MenuName from TableX X
    join TableY Y on X.DisplayOrder=Y.DisplayOrder) as Source
    PIVOT (SUM(GlobalMenuID) for MenuName  in (AK, AL, AR, AZ, CA, CO, CT) )
    as pivot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a dynamic query for columns as:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';
--Get column names for entire pivoting
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(SpreadCol)
  FROM (select distinct MenuName as SpreadCol 
        from tblX
       ) AS T;  
select @columns;

--and then PIVOT to get desired result as:

SET @sql = N'
SELECT entityId, entityIdentification, displayName, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(select globalMenuID, entityId, entityIdentification, displayName , menuName as SpreadCol
from tblX inner join tblY on tblY.displayOrder = tblX.displayOrder
) as D
PIVOT
(
  Max(globalMenuID) FOR SpreadCol IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS Pivot1
'

;
```

[Check Demo here](http://rextester.com/CXVACU45050)